# Diferente conteo entre len en keras y wc -l en el sistema

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, keras, count

Quiero cargar un conjunto de datos en `train/`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

ds_train_ = image_dataset_from_directory('train/',
                                        labels=categories,
                                        label_mode='binary',
                                        image_size = [128,128],
                                        interpolation='nearest',
                                        batch_size=64,
                                        shuffle = False)
```

Y me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_34/3535390885.py in <module>
      7                                         interpolation='nearest',
      8                                         batch_size=64,
----> 9                                         shuffle = False)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py in image_dataset_from_directory(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, color_mode, batch_size, image_size, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, interpolation, follow_links, crop_to_aspect_ratio, **kwargs)
    195       shuffle=shuffle,
    196       seed=seed,
--> 197       follow_links=follow_links)
    198 
    199   if label_mode == 'binary' and len(class_names) != 2:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py in index_directory(directory, labels, formats, class_names, shuffle, seed, follow_links)
     98                        'of files in the target directory. len(labels) is %s '
     99                        'while we found %s files in %s.' % (
--> 100                            len(labels), len(filenames), directory))
    101   else:
    102     i = 0

ValueError: Expected the lengths of `labels` to match the number of files in the target directory. len(labels) is 25000 while we found 0 files in train/.
```

Pero hizo:

```
! ls train | wc -l
```

Y obtengo 25000

Tambien hizo:

```
print(os.system('pwd'))
print(os.system('ls train | wc -l'))
```

Y obtengo:

```
/kaggle/working
0
25000
0
```

Aqui es parte del directorio train:

```
cat.0.jpg
cat.1.jpg
cat.10.jpg
cat.100.jpg
ls: write error: Broken pipe
```

Comment: ¿Puedes listar parte del directorio `train`?